# How to convert a symbol size in millimeter into that in meter by PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, generalization

Recently I am trying to use PyQGIS API to help auto-mapping in QGIS, and some symbols' overlapping on a map that is to be printed at a certain scale is not in accordance with cartography principles.

To solve this problem in a simplest way that one of two features will be "hidden" by setting its symbol size to 0 if the distance between the two features is less than the sum of the two features' symbol size in meter converted from the size in millimeter, I directly use `Diameter=MaxSymbolSize*CanvasScale/1000` to do the conversion, where Diameter represents the size in meter, `MaxSymbolSize=TestLayer.renderer().symbol().size()`, and `CanvasScale=iface.mapCanvas().scale()`. This can really handle the symbol overlap problem correctly, but I guess I think there should be some errors if the mapping region is considerable large.

I try to find the related API in PyQGIS and find some functions such as `convertFromMapUnits()`, `convertMetersToMapUnits()`, and `convertToMapUnits()` in `QgsRenderContext()` class. But the definition of MapUnits and so on in QGIS is a little confusing to me and their respective return values seem the same in different map scales.

I wonder how to understand correctly about the `QgsRendererContext()` class and how to convert a symbol size in millimeter into that in meter by PyQGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find I mistakenly constructed a `QgsRenderContext` object by directly using `QgsRenderContext()` and not using its `fromMapSettings()` function, that means my constructed object doesn't include the related render information, which makes the return value of `convertFromMapUnits()` and other functions seem meaningless.

Here is an example:

My project's projection is ESRI:102027 ,and the map canvas scale is 1:100000.

The wrong situation:
run

```
QgsRenderContext().convertFromMapUnits(200,0)
```

then return:

[image]

The right situation:
run

```
testRC = QgsRenderContext().fromMapSettings(iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings())
testRC.convertFromMapUnits(200,0)
```

then return:
[image]

The result should be equal with the result of using `Diameter=MaxSymbolSize*CanvasScale/1000` as mentioned in this question description in my opinion because I also have a try to measure the symbol size directly use the measurement tool as shown in the following picture(**note it's based on a Cartesian calculations** rather than ellipsoidal calculations):

[image]

and the symbol is:

[image]